# How to remove trailing slash from url in nginx?

Tags: nginx, server, configuration

I am running a server on nginx with PHP-FastCGI. Currently I have it setup so that it removes trailing slashes from my URLs and issues a 301 redirect. However, when I visit a directory that exists,"err_too_many_redirects"(if I try to check that such kind of links like site.com/images/ or other directory link return 403 code ), My server block looks like this:

```
server {
   server_name    example.com www.example.com;
   root           /var/www/example.com/html;
   index          index.html;

   rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

   error_page 404 403 /404.html;
   location = /404.html {
   internal;
}

   error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
   location = /500.html {
   internal;
}

   location / {

   try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ $uri/index.html $uri/index $uri/ =404;
}

listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Could anyone help me to find soultion for this problem?

Comment: The `$uri/` term together with your `rewrite` rule will create a loop. Try: `try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/index.html $uri/index =404;`

Comment: Thankyou it works for me. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $uri/ term together with your rewrite rule will create a loop. Try:

```
try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/index.html $uri/index =404;
```